# Hide tab if there are no attributes

Tags: attributes

I'm using tabs.phtml on my product pages.

This is the code

```
<ul class="extra-tabs">
    <?php foreach ($tabsCollection as $_index => $_tab): ?>
        <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
            <li id="extra_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>" class="<?php echo !$_index?' active first':(($_index==count($tabsCollection)-1)?' last':'')?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $_tab['title']?></a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php foreach ($tabsCollection as $_index => $_tab): ?>
    <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
        <div class="extra-tabs-content" id="extra_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>_contents"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias']) ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

However, this also shows if there are no attributes assigned to the product, so I need the tab not to show if there are no attributes assigned to the product.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try to use below code

```
<ul class="extra-tabs">
    <?php foreach ($tabsCollection as $_index => $_tab): ?>
        <?php if(trim(strip_tags($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])))): ?>
            <li id="extra_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>" class="<?php echo !$_index?' active first':(($_index==count($tabsCollection)-1)?' last':'')?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $_tab['title']?></a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php foreach ($tabsCollection as $_index => $_tab): ?>
    <?php if(trim(strip_tags($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])))): ?>
        <div class="extra-tabs-content" id="extra_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>_contents"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias']) ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```